# How to assign Subcategory to Category in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, model-view-controller, model, rails-console

When i want to add new Categories i fire up `rails console`
and type `Category.create(name: "Programming and Tech")`

When i want to add new Subcategories i type in rails console

`Subcategory.create(name: "Rails,Wordpress,php,Ruby...etc")` #those are **Subcategories** of the above **Main Category**

My website has 6 **Main** categories and i can easily create them.As well as subcategories like i showed above in rails console.
Every of the 6 **main** categories has 4-5 different **different** subcategories.

**Question:**

> How do i assign created by me subcategories to their corresponding
>   M**ain Category**

Thank you for time,any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Why don't you simply scaffold some simple CRUD interfaces for Categories and Subcategories?

Comment: I'd be happy to,but how would i do it?,can you please write an answer,about how would you go about it.Thank you.

Comment: Just check  guides.rubyonrails.org/command_line.html. Look for 'rails generate controller'. It should have the examples to get you going.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the rails console do this:

1.`category=Category.create(name: "Programming and Tech")`

2.`subcategory=Subcategory.create(name: "Rails")`

3.`category.subcategories << subcategory` #this will assign subcategory to the category.

And then see the result with:

`category.subcategories`

Comment: It works exactly as i wanted locally,but when i deploy to heroku the categories and subcategories are empty.Is there a way to make them permanent? thank you.

Comment: this is a temporary solution,how to make them permanent? thanks.

Comment: add categories and subcategories in `seeds.rb` use `heroku run rake db:seed` in the terminal after logged in to heroku.